# Отрисовка особого круга на канвасе

Tags: javascript, canvas

Имеется круг на канвасе

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(500,300, 250, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

Также есть ползунок под этим кругом

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="30" step="1" id="range">
```

Задача вообще нетривиальная, но нужна для одного прикольного математического фокуса. Необходимо, чтобы по дефолту на круге стояло 10 точек, от 0 до 9, на равном расстоянии. При изменении ползунка должны добавляться точки, то есть в положении ползунка 0 точек 10, в положении 1 11 итд, при этом разумеется точки должны раздвигаться, чтобы между ними было все время равное расстояние, и еще подписи возле каждой точки.
Данная схема реализуема на канвасе, или нужна какая-то другая магия? :D

Comment: Данная схема реализуема на канвасе.

Comment: Благодарю, а как?

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали?

Comment: В смысле точки должны быть по периметру окружности? Лежать на окружности?

Comment: Ну, круг и ползунок. Я представляю как выглядит каркас этой схемы, я только не представляю как ставить точки на определенном расстоянии на окружности. Я вообще не представляю как ставить точки на окружности.

Comment: Геометрия, 6-ой класс. (или 5-ый?)

Comment: Центр же окружности есть, дальше делите Math.PI*2 на количество точек. Получится угол. По углу и радиусу вычисляете каждую последующую точку) Первую возьмите x, y-radius

Comment: Класс, сразу ясно стало. Но спасибо

Comment: Данная схема реализуема на канвасе. Другая магия не нужна.

Comment: @Eternalblue, все сделал, в чем фокус то, математический?

Comment: Типо сложно так объяснить, вот видос https://youtu.be/qhbuKbxJsk8 (там на эльфийском!), я хотел сделать что то подобное, только типа наглядное пособие, по приколу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто вращать круг и расставлять точки)).

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

window.onresize = render;

function render(){
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 10;
  let h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  
  let x = w/2;
  let y = h/2;
  let radius = Math.min(w/2, h/2) - 25;

  let inp = document.getElementById('inp');
  inp.style.width = `${w - 10}px`;

  inp.oninput = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  let num = inp.value;
  let angle = Math.PI*2/num;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.font = '12px serif';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';

  for(let i=0; i < num; i++){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, -radius, 3, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.fillText(`${i}`, 0, - (radius + 6), 12);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
  }
  ctx.restore();
  }

  inp.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}

render();
```

```css
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="10" id="inp" min="0" max="30">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Впрочем, ползунок я уже сделал.

Comment: Подсказка: можно открыть на всю страницу, и, если input=range в фокусе, то можно пользоваться стрелочками вправо-влево. Если min=10 нужен, то так и укажите.

Comment: можно поменять `change` на `input`, будет веселее

Comment: Ага, точно веселее)) Спасибо!

Comment: на порядок, всегда пожалуйста

Comment: Это даже выглядит сложно